# ASP.NET Core REST Body contains characters before and after the Dto object

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

This problem can be reproduced by the following steps

1. Open Visual Studio 2019
2. Create a new project
3. ASP.NET Core web application
4. Use the Angular template
5. Create a sub directory in Controllers and call it WebApi
6. Add a new controller
7. Select Api Controller read/write actions
8. Name the Controller TestController
9. Add the following function to TestController

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("TList")]
   [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
   [Produces("application/json")]
   public ActionResult<TestDto> TList()
   {
       TestDto result = new TestDto();
       result.Title = "Title";
       result.DataList = new List<TestItem>();
       result.DataList.Add(new TestItem() { Title = "Test" });

   return Ok(result);
   }
   ```
10. Create a Folder and call it Models
11. Add the following DTO

```
    namespace WebApplication1.Models
    {
        public class TestDto
        {
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public List<TestItem> DataList { get; set; }
        }
        public class TestItem
        {
            public string Title { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

12. Start Fiddler
13. Press Play
14. Enter https://localhost:44383/api/test/tlist
15. In Fiddler you will see the following

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
> X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
> Date: Wed, 18 Dec 2019 07:38:29 GMT
>
> 2f
> {"title":"Title","dataList":[{"title":"Test"}]}
> 0
> ```

How can I get rid of the 2f and the 0 ?

Comment: Something else is mangling the response body. There's not enough here to diagnose. Generally, stuff like that is an encoding issue, but it's being sent as UTF8, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Chris Pratt What other information would you like ?

Comment: How/what is making the request?

Comment: I am using Fiddler making a Get on https://localhost:44317/2017/12/05/KnowHow/TList

Comment: With the following in the headerReferer: https://localhost:44317/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,de-CH;q=0.5,de;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Host: localhost:44317
Connection: Keep-Alive

Comment: @chris-pratt It's an Angular client

Comment: [Route("2017/12/05/[controller]")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    public class KnowHowController : ControllerBase

Comment: I am using Newtonsoft.Json Version="12.0.3" @ChrisPratt is there anything else I can provide to help solve the problem?

Comment: a bit moot but I think you misunderstand what Rest is (it's an architecture/set of principles). One of the fundamental principles of REST architecture is HATEOAS, creating an API that is self exploring. Based on your sample code you have a  HTTP-based interface, not a RESTful API.

Comment: @Kevin, No I understand HATEOAS, here it is about a technical problem how to solve a serialization problem. My Angular application breaks because it is not able to deserialize the body probably because of these characters. I thought that's what stackoverflow is about, present a problem as simple as you can and get some suggestions how to fix it. Here I don't understand why the question is marked down with little advice over what extra information is needed to solve the problem.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I have updated the question with a full set of steps how to reproduce it. Can you see what is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These characters are specific to Fiddler. They cannot been seen in Chrome or Postman. These characters do not effect the de-serialisation because the following code worked with a Rest response containing these characters

```
this.http.get('https://localhost:44383/api/test/TList').subscribe((data : TestDto) => {
  this.myData = data;
   this.title = data.title;
});
```